# Marshal char[][LENGTH] in c#

Tags: c#, c++, string, marshalling, dllimport

In a C# project I have difficulties to connect a C++ function coming from an external library. I guess this is a problem of string marshalling.

## In C++ there is the following function:

```
int compute(const char names[][LENGTH_1], char values[][LENGTH_2], const int n);
```

The goal is to provide:

- an read-only array containing "n" strings of LENGTH_1 characters
- an writable array containing "n" strings of LENGTH_2 characters

The function "compute" will write in the array "values" according to what is specified in "names".

## In tried in C# two different ways to connect the function

### Method 1

```
[DllImport("abcd.dll", EntryPoint="compute", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
internal static extern int Compute(StringBuilder [] names, StringBuilder [] values, int n);
```

I call it this way:

```
var names = new StringBuilder[number];
var descriptions = new StringBuilder[number];
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
  names[i] = new StringBuilder(LENGTH_1);
  descriptions[i] = new StringBuilder(LENGTH_2);
}
var error = Compute(names, descriptions, number);
```

### Method 2

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, Pack=4)]
internal struct StringName
{
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=64)] // LENGTH_1 = 64
  public string msg;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, Pack=4)]
internal struct StringValue
{
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=128)] // LENGTH_2 = 128
  public string msg;
}

[DllImport("abcd.dll", EntryPoint="compute", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
internal static extern int Compute(StringName[] names, ref StringValue[] values, int number);
```

I call it this way:

```
var names = new StringNames[number];
var values = new StringValue[number];
var error = Compute(names, ref values, number);
```

## Result

It crashes with no exceptions, the program is blocked on the function "Compute". I'm still unsure if the problem comes from the strings or from the external library.

Comment: Why did you add `Pack` to the attribute declaration? Were you just trying stuff at random? Remove everything that you tried at random and include the code that you feel should work.

Comment: The second variant has the best chance of success. The `ref` is wrong though. Use `[In]` on the first param, `[In, Out]` on the second. Not clear what the calling convention should be. All that said, I'm sceptical that the marshaller will marshal the strings back out. You might need to resort to some tricks to make that work.

Comment: Thanks! I added Pack=4 because I previously had problems with it but now you are right, this is not necessary. I changed "ref" into [In, Out] and I have no crash anymore! However the strings are empty, could you please explain a bit more about "some tricks to make that work"?

Comment: You can use a fixed byte array to make the type be a plain value type. Then the payload will be marshaled both ways. You'd need to include a string property that read from and wrote to the payload. That forces you to use `unsafe`. If you don't want to do that then you could have empty structs but with `Size` specified in the `StructLayout` attribute. This will then make sure that the data is present and marshalled. Access it again using a property whose getter and setter pin the structure using `GCHandle`, and then use the `Marshal` class to convert to/from string.

Comment: If you have a solution to your problem then post an answer, do not edit your question.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. Finally it worked already, I forgot a "Out". I wrote the solution, you saved my day :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As found by David, the keyword "ref" was wrong. Here is the changes with method 2.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
internal struct StringName
{
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=LENGTH_1)]
  public string msg;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
internal struct StringValue
{
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=LENGTH_2)]
  public string msg;
}

[DllImport("abcd.dll", EntryPoint="compute", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
internal static extern int Compute([In] StringName[] names, [In, Out] StringValue[] values, int number);
```

I call it this way:

```
var names = new StringNames[number];
// ... here the initialization of "names" ... //
var values = new StringValue[number];
var error = Compute(names, values, number);
// ... here the processing of "values" ... //
```